# How to load cookies and open multiple tabs with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, web-crawler

If I provide the path to the firefox profile to the program it will open multiple windows, but without is it opens multiple tabs. I need it to open multiple tabs. Any ideas?

```
# driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = r"C:\Users\Aron\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\azz050gk.default-release")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(r'C:\Users\Aron\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\azz050gk.default-release')
driver.get(sites['site'][0])
for i in range(size - 1,0, -1):
    driver.execute_script("window.open('" + sites['site'][i] +"');")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this to save and load cookies:

```
# ===========================================================
def save_cookies(driver, site_name):
    cookies = driver.get_cookies()

    for cookie in cookies:
        if isinstance(cookie.get('expiry'), float):
            cookie['expiry'] = int(cookie['expiry'])
    pickle.dump(cookies, open(site_name + ".pkl", "wb"))


# =================================================================================
def load_cookies(driver, site_name):
    if not os.path.isfile(site_name + ".pkl"):
        return

    cookies = pickle.load(open(site_name + ".pkl", "rb"))
    for cookie in cookies:
        driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

You need to get the site, load the cookies, reload, save the cookies. The first time you must manually accept the cookies. After that it should be saved.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import pickle
import time

# ==============================================================
def save_cookies(driver, site_name):
    cookies = driver.get_cookies()

    for cookie in cookies:
        if isinstance(cookie.get('expiry'), float):
            cookie['expiry'] = int(cookie['expiry'])
    pickle.dump(cookies, open(site_name + ".pkl", "wb"))


# ===============================================================
def load_cookies(driver, site_name):
    if not os.path.isfile(site_name + ".pkl"):
        return

    cookies = pickle.load(open(site_name + ".pkl", "rb"))
    for cookie in cookies:
        driver.add_cookie(cookie)


# ==========================================================

# open the web driver ----------------------------------
project_dir = os.path.split(os.getcwd())[0] + '/../'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.join(project_dir, 'chromedriver.exe'))

site_url = 'https://bol.com'
site_name = 'bol.com'

driver.get(site_url)  # site must be loaded before cookies can be loaded
load_cookies(driver, site_name)
driver.get(site_url)  # now the site is reloaded using the cookies

# get some time to manually accept the cookies the first run
time.sleep(10)

# do your scraping 

save_cookies(driver, site_name)

driver.close()
```

Next time the 'accept cookies' should not show up.

This works for me opening a new tab for the chrome driver on windows:

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com/")

#open tab
driver.execute_script('''window.open("http://bings.com","_blank");''')

driver.close()
```

Comment: This is how I implemented is, but doesn't seem to work :S
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()  
    driver.get(sites['site'][0])  
    load_cookies(driver,'0')  
    input("Enter")  
    save_cookies(driver,'0')  
    for i in range (size - 1, 0 , - 1):  
        driver.execute_script("window.open('" + sites['site'][i] +"');")  
        load_cookies(driver,str(i))  
        input("Enter")  
        save_cookies(driver,str(i))  
I have to open multiple sites, so I open them one by one, and load then save the cookies every time, but the second time I open it still asks to accept them.

Comment: It didn't work, you're right.I have added an extra line. Driver first needs a page loaded before it can load the cookies, after that you can load the cookies. If you then reload the page, it has the required cookies and it should be ok.

Comment: When the second driver.get() opens the site it won't ask me to accept the cookies, but when I run the program again it won't open the cookies so I have to accept them again.

Comment: What do you mean with 'it won't open the cookies'? Are they disappeard?

Comment: They are in the folder where I saved them, but when I rerun the program I still have to accept and cookies I accepted before.

Comment: I have now uploaded a fully working example. Tested it several times. It keeps working the way it should.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211210/discussion-between-mace-and-pilv).

Comment: yes I did. I'll try and find other methods for this. Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: I hope you will succeed :-))